# how can i choose one email from all email Map list?

Tags: apex, map, list, emailmessage

I'm just starting with salesforce and need some help.

I need to get one related email from Map email list. I manage to get all emails with this query, but don't know how to get one I needed. Any help appreciated

```
    List<EmailMessage> email = [
        SELECT Id, FromAddress, ToAddress, ParentId
        FROM EmailMessage 
        ORDER BY Id DESC
    ];

    System.debug(email);

    Map<Id, List<String>> emailMapTo = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
    for(EmailMessage eml : email) {

        List<String> emailList = emailMapTo.get(eml.ParentId);
        if(emailList == null) {
            emailList = new List<String>();
        }
        emailList.add(eml.ToAddress);
        emailMapTo.put(eml.ParentId, emailList);
    }

    Map<Id, List<String>> emailMapFrom = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
    for(EmailMessage eml : email) {

        List<String> emailList = emailMapFrom.get(eml.ParentId);
        if(emailList == null) {
            emailList = new List<String>();
        }
        emailList.add(eml.FromAddress);
        emailMapFrom.put(eml.ParentId, emailList);
    }

    System.debug(emailMapTo);
    System.debug(emailMapFrom);
```

Comment: You need to explain the requirement you are working to i.e. what identifies the "one I needed"?

Comment: I need to compare if email sent (when agent replies) is the same as email from which case was opened (customer opens case with email)

Comment: One thing to not do is to pull everything into memory doing the work via Apex as that can consume a lot of time and also hit governor limits. Use `where` clauses to get the database to pick out what is needed.